# Filter subject in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

i want filter Subject from rxjs lib but the old method doesnt work any more

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Message {
    channel: string;
    data: any;
}

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
    private message$: Subject<Message>

    constructor(){
        this.message$ = new Subject<Message>();
    }

    public publish<T>(message: T): void {
        const channel = (<any>message.constructor).name;
        this.message$.next({ channel: channel, data: message });
    }

    public of<T>(messageType: { new(...args: any[]): T }): Observable<T> {
        const channel = (<any>messageType).name;
        return this.message$.filter(m => m.channel === channel).map(m => m.data);
    }
}
```

Error: **Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Subject'**

how can i filter Subject?

Comment: To complementary Adrian Brand answer, see the guide to migration: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the pipe function

```
this.message$.pipe(
  filter(m => m.channel === channel),
  map(m => m.data)
);
```

You imported the functions, they are not methods on the observable object. This was changed in RxJs 6 so that the operators could be tree shake-able and only the ones you import are in your build.